# How do I make second div move down and up with the w and s keys on the keyboard?

Tags: javascript

The Problem I'm having is that the everytime i trigger the event key for w and s characters, it logs on the console showing the w event key being triggered, but nothing happens to the div as i want it to move up and down. I tried to use the code structure as the first div but could only get a console.log(e). How do i make it move up or down?

I'm building pong on basically div elements, and some js. I got the first paddle to work. When i tried to the run the same code but using keydown funtion and use e.key to equal w. It for some reason is shown console logging the w key being press down, but it never moves the second div.

```js
var playerOne = document.getElementById("playerOnePaddle");
var playerTwo = document.getElementById("playerTwoPaddle");

console.log(playerOne);
console.log(playerTwo);

 window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
   var y = parseInt(getComputedStyle(playerOne).top);
   e.preventDefault();
   
   if (e.key === "ArrowUp") {
      y -= 1;
      playerOne.style.top = y + "px";
      console.log(e);
    } else if (e.key === "ArrowDown") {
      y += 1;
      playerOne.style.top = y + "px";
      console.log(e);
    }
});
  
window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e){
  var x = parseInt(getComputedStyle(playerTwo).top);
  e.preventDefault();
  
  if (e.key === 'w') {
    x -= 1;
    playerOne.style.top = x + "px";
    console.log(e);
  } else if (e.key === 's') {
    x = x + 1;
    playerOne.style.top = x + "px";
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

```css
#backBoard {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}

#playerOnePaddle {
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 4px;
  width: 4px;
}

#playerTwoPaddle {
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 390px;
  width: 4px;
}

#ball {
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50px;
  width: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="backBoard">
  <div id="playerOnePaddle"></div>
  <div id="playerTwoPaddle"></div>
  <div id="ball"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You event listeners both reference `playerOne`

Answer (score 0):

in the second keydown callback you're changing the style of **playerOne** where you would need to add it to **playerTwo**.

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you are expecting (run the snippet) :

1. you don't have to make two exact event listeners just add all your code into one and use conditions.
2. your `x` and `y` were being reset each time the event function is executed so i moved them out of the callback function .
3. you were using on both events the same player `playerOne`.

```js
var playerOne = document.getElementById("playerOnePaddle");
var playerTwo = document.getElementById("playerTwoPaddle");
var y = parseInt(getComputedStyle(playerOne).top);
var x = parseInt(getComputedStyle(playerTwo).top)


 window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   if (e.key === "ArrowUp") {
      y -= 1;
      playerOne.style.top = y+"px";
     
    } else if (e.key === "ArrowDown") {
      y += 1;
      playerOne.style.top = y+"px";
 
    } else if (e.key === 'w') {
     x -= 1;
     playerTwo.style.top = x+"px";

    } else if (e.key === 's') {
     x = x + 1;
     playerTwo.style.top = x+"px";
  
    }
});
```

```css
#backBoard {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}

#playerOnePaddle {
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 4px;
  width: 4px;
}

#playerTwoPaddle {
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 390px;
  width: 4px;
}

#ball {
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50px;
  width: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="backBoard">
  <div id="playerOnePaddle"></div>
  <div id="playerTwoPaddle"></div>
  <div id="ball"></div>
</div>
```